# Telerik RadTreeView not support Accordion jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, telerik, telerik-mvc

I want to use Accordion jquery for collapsing and expending nodes (If there are two child nodes of one Root and when click on one child node then for that node sub child node should be expand and another Child node should be Collapse).

suggest me any idea...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is really confusing. Do you mean you want to use third party Accordion jQuery with RadTreeView?

Comment: yes... I want to use  Accordion jQuery with RadTreeView?

Comment: You can implement in RadTreeView to expand only one node at time. I'm wondering why you want to use third party Accordion jQuery.

Comment: you are right. but my problem is.. when i am clicking on one child node then other child node should be collapsed.(suppose their are two child nodes and they have their subchilds. then what i need, when i click on any child node then other expanded child node should be collapse)

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved now with one control of Telerik RadTreeView,i.e OnClientNodeClicking.

Example:-

OnClientNodeClicking="ClientNodeClicking"

Javascript:-

function ClientNodeClicking(sender, eventArgs) {
        var node = eventArgs.get_node();

```
    node.toggle();

    if (node.get_nodes().get_count()) {
        CollapseSiblings(node);
    }
}

function CollapseSiblings(node) {
    var parent = node.get_parent();
    var siblings = parent.get_nodes();
    var siblingsCount = siblings.get_count();

    for (var nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < siblingsCount; nodeIndex ++) {
        var siblingNode = siblings.getNode(nodeIndex);

        if ((siblingNode != node) && (siblingNode.get_expanded())) {
            siblingNode.collapse();
            return;
        }
    }
```